# Accessing package from another directory - Flash CS6

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

[image]So I'm still generally new to Flash, and I'm currently trying to access a package containing many .as files from another directory. The first file path I have is:

```
Documents/Website/Flash/comps/colors
```

This "colors" folder contains my Main.fla and my Main.as, as well as a few other .as files.

My second file path, which contains the package I want called "AllStuff" is located in

```
Documents/Website/Flash/AllStuff
```

I'm not sure exactly how to access elements located in "AllStuff" from my Main.fla. I've gone to "Edit Actionscript Settings" and added the path to "AllStuff" in the Source Path, and then I'm trying to do

```
import AllStuff;
```

in my Main.as file. Am I completely wrong?

**Edit**

I tried:

```
import Button; //Button.as is a file inside AllStuff
```

and it compiles but I'm getting an Argument Error in my code somewhere. Even though I have set a source path to "AllStuff", I still have libraries saved in the same folder as Main.as and Main.fla that I would like to access. By adding in a source path to "AllStuff", does this mess with the libraries in the folder containing Main.fla and Main.as?

Comment: You need to add the correct source paths in the actionscript settings (you can get there from the publish settings then click the wrench icon I think it is besides the actionscript 3 drop down).   If you .as files are in the root of a directory in your source path, you don't need to import them from any other .as files that are also in root directories

Comment: Add a screenshot of your source paths in the actionscript settings.

Comment: Added. Do I need to add the file path that Main.fla is in as well?

Comment: Are you actually getting an import error though?  If it compiles as you say, then the problem has nothing to do with your class paths.  If flash can't find an import it will tell you in the form of a compiler error.

Comment: /Users/jruloff/Documents/WebsiteFlash/AllStuff/Button.as, Line 1 5001: The name of package 'AllStuff' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. /Users/jruloff/Documents/Website/Flash/AllStuff/Button.as....I get this error whether i import Button or not

Comment: in your `AllStuff.as` - does it say `package {`  or do you have a package name defined?  Any .as files in a source path root directory should defined as `package {`  (no package name)

Comment: AllStuff is a folder, it is not a file. In a file path, are a folder and a package different?

Comment: The package name needs to represent the folder structure,  so root would be `package {`  any .as files inside an **AllStuff** folder should be `package AllStuff {`.     Another folder in AllStuff would be `package AllStuff.subFolder {`   etc.

Comment: Yeah Button.as has package AllStuff. Do I import Button to access Button class, or how do I access it then? Am I doing it wrong? Sorry this is probably a stupid question I'm just still getting used to Flash and it's very tedious. I very much appreciate your help @LDMS.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, your have `AllStuff` as a source path, which makes it a root directory,  so stuff in there should actually be `package {`   -  I'd stick with that too, because you don't want to have two different source paths that can lead to the same files (say if you were go up a directory and add `Documents/Website/Flash`)

Comment: So this is actually a project that I'm taking on, and I can't modify the existing files, aka they must stay as AllStuff. How can I access them knowing this?

Comment: You could try changing the source path to be `Documents/Website/Flash` instead of `Documents/Website/Flash/AllFiles`, but it may confuse Flash as per my last comment (as both source paths would lead to the colors directory but with different paths). - Then again, maybe Flash is smart enough to figure it out

Comment: I believe I've got it, except I'm getting some random error saying undefined methods to random classes. It shouldn't have any affect on this but I'll try and debug it some more. Thank you so much for your help!